# Change color for some seconds using only CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to change the color of a div on hover for X seconds, then return to its original color using only CSS?

I do not want any fade ins or outs between the color. For example, if I want to change the color of the div to yellow for 1 second on hover, it must remain yellow for 1 second, then immediately return to the original color.

This (http://jsfiddle.net/hZ49y/1/) is what I have so far. It works as I described above, but I feel that this way of using `animation` is not intuitive and hard to understand. Should I stick to using JavaScript for this purpose? What are some alternatives?

Comment: I think this is only possible using javascript or jQuery

Comment: Think your best bet is JavaScript with a timer

Comment: @Gert B., It actually works with only CSS (please see the updated jsfiddle), but it is kind of like a "hack", and I am looking for a better approach.

Comment: What do you find 'unintuitive' about it? That's the only approach (that I'm aware of) that would do as you require; and, however 'unintuitive' you might find it, I strongly suspect it's *more* intuitive than using JavaScript with a `setTimeout`/`setInterval` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but requires some math!

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/PeBtX/)**

You must use another parameter of animation: `animation-iteration-count` as `1`

```
div:hover {
    animation: myfirst 2s 1;
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
    0%      {background:red;}
    25%     {background:yellow;}
    75%     {background:yellow;}
    100%    {background:red;}
}
```

This is going to perform a  **4s** animation with the following *"key-frames"*:

> 0s > red
>   1s > yellow (stays 2 seconds here)
>   3s > yellow
>   4s > red

The only problem is that the animation stops on mouse out. But you can use `javascript` to activate the animation (by toggle a class), so the animation doesn't stops on mouse out.

---

**Update:**

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/PeBtX/2/)** with `js` to control `css` animation.

Answer (score 2):

CSS animations don't explicitly allow instantaneous, non-transitioning changes from frame-to-frame, but you can achieve the effect in practice by setting keyframes so close to each other that it's practically impossible for an intervening frame to come in ([forked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/GnLE9/)):

```
@keyframes myfirst
{
0%      {background:yellow;}
99.999% {background:yellow;}
100%    {background:red;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this with `animation`. It works exactly as you asked, the only problem is that after page load the box is yellow for a second.

http://jsfiddle.net/4TcMP/1/