# How to correctly set an WPF EventTrigger in style?

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

I have a WPF style that is a border. It is used for a button.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp" Handler="RegularButtonRelease"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#FF444444" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1.2" >
                                <GradientStop Color="#ffaaaaaa" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>                             
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <!--some style -->
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!--some style -->                                
                    </Trigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:2" AutoReverse="False">
                                <ColorAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    FillBehavior="Stop" To="Tomato"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to set the border background color to a different one for a given time, when I release the mouse click on the button. (e.g. the button is black when pressed, and when I release, it changes to red, then changes back to white)

Using the above code, I can see the button color keep changing  after I release mouse button, and my event handler `RegularButtonRelease` is fired continuously too.
Soon the appplication hangs, and gives me a `System.StackOverflowException` 
exception.

If I take away the `EventTrigger` in style, my applications perform correctly, so my EventTrigger must be wrong.

My question is, how could I correctly set a background color change at mouse button up (using the EventTrigger  or something else)?

*UPDATE:*

I try to set the border and background at the same time using:

```
<ColorAnimation 
    Duration="0:0:0.8" 
    Storyboard.TargetName="border" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
    To="Red"/>
<ColorAnimation 
    Duration="0:0:0.8" 
    Storyboard.TargetName="border" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
    To="Red"/>
```

This time the border line is changing to red, works like a charm. But the background still sits there, no any changes.

How can I correctly change my background?

Comment: Add this line to your `Triggers` tag - `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your mistakes : 
You are trying to change `Color` of `Background` which is not possible as it is set to `LinearGradientBrush`, and secondly you have not set `Storyboard.TargetName` at all.

I have done some changes, first : Assign `x:Name` to second `GradientStop`, and then use this `x:Name`  as `Storyboard.TargetName="C2"` in animation.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp" Handler="RegularButtonRelease"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#FF444444" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1.2" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#ffaaaaaa" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop x:Name="C2" Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <!--some style -->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!--some style -->
                        </Trigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False">
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="C2"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                                        FillBehavior="Stop" To="Red"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this example :

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

For reference:

[Change color of Button when Mouse is over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073294/wpf-button-mouse-over-change-color)

[How do you change Background for a Button MouseOver in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf)

Coming to the `System.StackOverflowException` part, according to MSDN you can get `StackOverflowExceptions` by creating too many large objects on the stack, it usually happens because your code has got into a state where it is calling the same chain of functions over and over again. Something like recursion.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but my style already has a `IsPressed` tragger that change the border background. I want to have another color when I release mouse, for ~1 second period.

Comment: Something like that of this in [Pietu1998 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21113588/5588347)?

Comment: Uh, that does not help me. However now I can change the border line color, only fail at changing background. I edited the main post.

Comment: Make sure the Background isn't set in the Button itself, as it would override any Style changes. Use a Setter in the Style for the default background color.